# Add submenu indicator to li item plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, submenu

i've looked around on stackoverflow but only found a way to do the thing i want with jQuery. The code i found is this:

```
$("li:has(ul)").each(function(){
    $(this).find(">a").addClass("hasSubmenu");
});
```

Now I would like to turn that into plain Javascript. So I don't need to include the jQuery librarie for this short piece of code.

Can somebody help me with turning this into JS code?

Comment: I've come up that I can get the ul elements with: `document.getElementsByTagName('li')` But not experienced enough in JS to check if an li element has ul elements and than add a class to it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two answers here that I see. In modern browsers, you can use the `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` methods to perform queries similar to jQuery:

```
var ulChildrenOfLi = document.querySelectorAll('li>ul');
for (var u = 0, ulen = ulChildrenOfLi.length; u < ulen; u++) {
    var liParent = ulChildrenOfLi[u].parentElement,
        aChildOfLi = liParent.querySelector('li>a');
    if (aChildOfLi) {
        aChildOfLi.className = aChildOfLi.className.replace("hasSubmenu", '') + " hasSubmenu";
    }
}
```

If you have to support IE, you could go with a bit more code:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
    var li = lis[i],
        uls = li.getElementsByTagName('ul'),
        children = li.children;
    if (uls.length !== 0) {
        for (var c = 0, cl = children.length; c < cl; c++) {
            var kid = children[c];
            kid.className = kid.className.replace("hasSubmenu", '') + " hasSubmenu";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle with both: http://jsfiddle.net/ppxcy/1/

Comment: The second solution worked perfect for me! Thanks for your answer. For future visitors with this problem, I now used `#item ul li a.hasSubmenu:after{content: ">";}` to show wether an item has a submenu or not with the following indicator: ">"

Answer (score 1):

You amy try this

```
var nav=document.getElementById('nav'), lis=nav.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(i=0;i<lis.length;i++)
{
    if(lis[i].hasChildNodes())
    {
        var childUl=lis[i].getElementsByTagName('ul');
        if(childUl.length)
            lis[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].className+=" hasSubmenu";
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKmyV/2/).

Comment: This also is a proper solution which could be used instead of the jQuery, thanks.